# Gmail API: permanent token access

Tags: php, access-token, gmail-api

After many researches I can now retrieve my Gmail inbox with my PHP code. Now I want to know if it's possible to get a permanent token access for the API without being forced to log in with OAuth.

I'm making a small application that would retrieve 3 different Gmail inboxes and people who would work with my app won't waste their time authorizing my Gmail app to the different inboxes.

I mean, is there a way to avoid authorizing each time I try to retrieve my Gmail inbox like a permanent token access I'll get just once then store it into my database?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such thing as permanent token, but there's refresh token:

> [Handling authorization
>   requests](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server)
>
> Exchange the authorization code for an access token
>
> The authorization code is a one-time code that your server can
>   exchange for an access token. This access token is passed to the Gmail
>   API to grant your application access to user data for a limited time.
>
> If your application requires offline access, the first time your app
>   exchanges the authorization code, it also receives a refresh token
>   that it uses to receive a new access token after a previous token has
>   expired. Your application stores this refresh token (generally in a
>   database on your server) for later use.
>
> Important: Always store user refresh tokens. If your application needs
>   a new refresh token it must send a request with the approval_prompt
>   query parameter set to force. This will cause the user to see a dialog
>   to grant permission to your application again.

Here's a snippet from the [Gmail API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php)

```
// Refresh the token if it's expired.
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
  }
```

Comment: very time saving and helpful answer